# Stopping youtube video once it reaches a point

Tags: youtube, gdata-api, youtube-api, gdata

It looks like the YouTube API does not have a way to stop a video playing once it reaches a certain point. It has a way to start it at a certain point, but not to stop it at a certain point. I'm wondering if there's a workaround for this? or maybe I glanced over it without noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some repetitive polling of the time elapsed with player.getCurrentTime() and then when it reaches the point you want, call player.stopVideo(). If that's a little too busy, you could use a timer and only start polling after a certain time had elapsed.